# COMPUTE Command in SPSS equals sign was not found

Tags: spss

I am executing the following in SPSS:

```
DO IF (A1=4).
COMPUTE (A1_COR=1).
ELSE IF (A1~=4).
COMPUTE (A1_COR=0).
END IF.
EXECUTE.
```

Can anyone see why I am receiving the, "An equals sign was not found when expected after the target variable" error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should looks like this:

```
DO IF (A1=4).
COMPUTE A1_COR=1.
ELSE.
COMPUTE A1_COR=0.
END IF.
EXECUTE.
```